# Custom organized data accessing via classes and constructors

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

struggling To achieve a solution for a basic Task:

**working with more than one `Sql Data table`, as a source, for a WebSite application...**

that's what leads me here once again... seeking for an Experienced  `C# .net` Developers Help.

i was just trying to add some basic logic for a proper implementation,Like using

a dedicated namespace & classes, To Hold reference for All `DATABASE tables`,

<sub>(before i try working / learning about `Entities Framework` approach.)</sub>

i would like to try implement same of **basic** features of `EF` ...by my self, and that way... i will also learn how to properly work with classes.

as it is so far ... structured **:**  <sub>**with my little knowledge**</sub>

a '*helper*'..  `namespace` ,  say the company name is: `HT technologies`

so  I've named the namespace  `HT_DbSchema` ...that contains **:**

- tables **names**

```C#
  public sealed class HTDB_Tables
  {
    public const string Customers= "Customers";
    public const string Times= "Times";
  }
```

- tables **IDs**

```C#
 public sealed class HT_tblIDs
 {
    public const int tblCustomersID = 1, tblTimesID = 2;
 }
```

- tables **Columns Lists** ...(just one example)

```C#
public class HTDB_Cols
{

      public class tblCustomers
      {
           public const string CustId  = "custId",
                               CustName  = "custName",
                               CellPhone  = "cellPhone" .... etc'
      }
}
```

and as all those 3 classes are serving all projects ..

there's another helper class for `constructor` Per Table For the Current Project

```C#
public class DBMetaDetails
{
       public struct DbTable
       {

             public string TableName { get; set; }
             public int TableID { get; set; }
       }
}
```

so still these are all construction / helpers Classes and are separated from the project,

now for current project

What is The Appropriate way to get it done, using above Classes and constructor within a project 
 <sub>(i could name those templates)</sub>

what i was doing so far to implement some order is :

```C#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      .... some other App inits here
    }

    else
    {

    }    

    // this method should be the one that instanciates the DbTable struct
   //and set the values of tables name and "ID"
   setTablesReferences(); 
}
```

### And Here's where the confusion starts :

in a day by day usage i want to try implement it in a WebSite application :

```C#
public void setTableReferences()
{
    DBMetaDetails.DbTable CustMeta = new DBMetaDetails.DbTable();
    DBMetaDetails.DbTable TimesMeta = new DBMetaDetails.DbTable();

}
```

so now i need to set `CustMeta` & `TimesMeta` details(`id`s &  `name`s)

the `struct` has a kind of a template structure a kind'a systematic technique to initialize and assign values, so it brings some decent order to my logic with it's existence .

**so what is the confusing part ?**

from one point of view(safety), i need those tables detailes to be `readonly`

so `DbTable.TableID`, and `DbTable.TableName` would not get overWriten by mistake.

having said that, **there should be only one place it could be SET** ... a dedicated section of the application,  like `setTableReferences()` above,... there i might add :

```C#
CustMeta.TableID = HT_tblIDs.tblCustomersID
CustMeta.TableName = HTDB_Tables.Customers;
```

on the other hand, i need the information of the tables to be Accessible,

so if let's say i would like to add those `DataTables` into a `DataSet`

```C#
DataSet ALLTablesSet = new DataSet();

// assuming the SQL actions already been taken in another method previosly...
// so DataTable is already retrived from DB 
//...but only as a short usage example:

AllTablesSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable(CustMeta.TableName));
```

My Question is What is the Correct Way to work with structs ...  as in My Scenario,

So in one section of app:  you would initialize - assign it with a value privately.

and from other sections of the app you could **use** its value (Only For **Readings**)

so that way, the application will not be able to access it's value for writing,
only by reading values, i think it should be trough another (Public ReadOnly) Variable.

so that variable was meant to be exposed ...and it's value could not be "harmed"

Comment: I think it's a good idea to simplify your question by using less code samples and text formatting and adding more description about what exactly is your final goal. You might want to take a closer look and start learning about the classes in the `System.Data` and `System.Data.SqlClient` namespaces.

Comment: @AlexFilipovici i can understand that you missed the whole point of the post. i wasn't looking for .net tools, the whole question is about instance of a struct that needs to be assigned with values  (so not being a `read only` type of variable) its a problem cause i need the values to be accessible but only for read purposes, the rest of the code is there to add proper background for the issue= struct holds name + id of an object and needded to be assigned first, then another **public** variable to expose the value for reads only, i wanted to learn a proper implemetation for that scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, the way I would prevent other code from modifying it is by removing the setters on the properties. However, you still need to set them at some point, so rather than removing the setters completely, you can just make them private. For example:

```
public string TableName { get; private set; }
```

If you do this, the only place you can set this data is within the struct itself, so you would need to create a constructor that took the initial values you wanted. So something like:

```
public struct DbTable
{
    public DbTable(string tableName, int tableId)
    {
        this.TableName = tableName;
        this.TableID = tableId;
    }

    public string TableName { get; private set; }
    public int TableID { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: you're a savior (: , i just need to check on this now through the application , see how could i access it and how to retreive values from the struct . so i guess (looking at your code once again should be simple . setting : instaciate it with say name is Dbtbl. `DbTbl.TableName="Customers"`  so when would it be possible to hide it is while having a public class in the program that will make that instance within it's scope the instance should be private and i could then use its value to assign to a public variable ... seems like a nice solution Kazetsukai (i hope i got it right)

Comment: So the only place you will be able to set the values is when you first construct the object. That will look something like `DbTable table = new DbTable("NameOfTable", 3);`